# Change DataSource of SSRS Report with Powershell

Tags: powershell, datasource, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to ahange data sources of multiple SSRS Report with Powershell to one shared data source on my reporting server. Here my code:

```
cls;  
$reportserver = "myServer";<br/>
$url = "http://$($reportserver)/reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx?WSDL";";<br/>
$ssrs = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $url -UseDefaultCredential -Namespace "ReportingWebService";

[ReportingWebService.DataSource[]] $myDataSource = new-object ReportingWebService.DataSource
$myDataSource[0].Name = "myDS"";<br/>
$myDataSource[0].Item = New-Object ReportingWebService.DataSourceReference<br/>
$myDataSource[0].Item.Reference = "/Data Sources/MyDS"<br/>

$reports = $ssrs.ListChildren('/DH', $false)

$reports | ForEach-Object {<br/>
$reportPath = $_.path<br/>
 Write-Host "Report: " $reportPath<br/>
 $dataSources = $ssrs.GetItemDataSources($reportPath)<br/>
 $dataSources | ForEach-Object {<br/>
              Write-Host "Old source: $($_.Name), $($_.Item.ConnectString)"<br/>
              $ssrs.SetItemDataSources($reportPath, $myDataSource)<br/>
              Write-Host "New source: $($_.Name), $($_.Item.ConnectString)"<br/>
          }<br/>

 Write-Host "------------------------"
}
```

But I'm getting the following error when calling "SetItemDataSources"-method:

```
***Argument "1" having the value "ReportingWebService.DataSource[]" of "SetItemDataSources" can not be converted to type "ReportingWebService.DataSource[]".***
```

The question is: What's wrong? The types are the SAME!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks e82.eric!

you led me to the working solution. Here it is:

```
cls;

#Set variables:
$reportserver = "myServer";
$newDataSourcePath = "/Data Sources/MyDS"
$newDataSourceName = "MyDS";
$reportFolderPath = "/DH"
#------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ssrs = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $url -UseDefaultCredential

$reports = $ssrs.ListChildren($reportFolderPath, $false)

$reports | ForEach-Object {
            $reportPath = $_.path
            Write-Host "Report: " $reportPath
            $dataSources = $ssrs.GetItemDataSources($reportPath)
            $dataSources | ForEach-Object {
                            $proxyNamespace = $_.GetType().Namespace
                            $myDataSource = New-Object ("$proxyNamespace.DataSource")
                            $myDataSource.Name = $newDataSourceName
                            $myDataSource.Item = New-Object ("$proxyNamespace.DataSourceReference")
                            $myDataSource.Item.Reference = $newDataSourcePath

                            $_.item = $myDataSource.Item

                            $ssrs.SetItemDataSources($reportPath, $_)

                            Write-Host "Report's DataSource Reference ($($_.Name)): $($_.Item.Reference)"
                            }

            Write-Host "------------------------" 
            }
```

Comment: Can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824616/ssrs-setitemdatasource-giving-exception

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem.

Its not a great solution but according to http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/273120-bug-when-using-namespace-parameter-new-webserviceproxy.html.  The namespace parameter of New-WebServiceProxy is somewhat broken.  The post suggests using the auto generated namespace which ended up working for me so I think you could do this.

```
$reportserver = "myServer"
$url = "http://$($reportserver)/reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx?WSDL"
$ssrs = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $url -UseDefaultCredential

$proxyNamespace = $ssrs.GetType().Namespace

$myDataSource = New-Object ("$proxyNamespace.DataSource") 
$myDataSource[0].Name = "myDS"
$myDataSource[0].Item = New-Object ("$proxyNamespace.DataSourceReference")
$myDataSource[0].Item.Reference = "/Data Sources/MyDS"

$reports = $ssrs.ListChildren('/DH', $false)

$reports | ForEach-Object {
$reportPath = $.path
Write-Host "Report: " $reportPath
$dataSources = $ssrs.GetItemDataSources($reportPath)
$dataSources | ForEach-Object {
Write-Host "Old source: $($.Name), $($.Item.ConnectString)"
$ssrs.SetItemDataSources($reportPath, @($myDataSource))
Write-Host "New source: $($.Name), $($_.Item.ConnectString)"
}

Write-Host "------------------------" }
```

Comment: good idea! now the error is different: "The data source 'myDS' cannot be found". It is strange - I know that this datasource DOES exist! :(

Comment: I get error: Property 'Name' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
  
$myDataSource is Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1NG_ReportService2005_asmx_WSDL.DataSource

I think is $myDataSource.Name.

Comment: what version of ssrs are you using?  Is it in native mode or sharepoint?

Answer (score 4):

I have packaged up this info in two nice scripts:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-SSRS-Data-Source-19360302

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-SSRS-Data-Source-3b074747

Enjoy!

Comment: any version without use Sharepoint, only SSRS ? For me fails in "get-spweb".

Comment: IvanJ thanks for the scripts. It saved my bacon and worked out great. @Kiquenet Make sure that you are running this from a SharePoint Management Shell, or have the SharePoint PowerShell snapin installed.

Comment: Getting below error for SP2013 "Exception calling "GetItemDataSources" with "1" argument(s): "The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' are insufficient for performing this operation. --->"

Comment: As far as I can tell, the sharepoint stuff doesn't exist, or can't be installed anymore (WIndows 10)