# SSRS SetItemDataSource giving exception

Tags: reporting-services, powershell-4.0

Hello all I am trying to set the datasource to the created report but I am getting an exception as mentioned

This is the code I am using

```
$Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportingServiceUrl -UseDefaultCredential
$ReportName = "MyReport"
$path="/"
$allitems = $Proxy.ListChildren("/",$true)
#Select the newest report with correct name
$ThisReport = $allitems | where {($_.Name -eq $ReportName) } | Sort-Object ModifiedDate -Descending | Select -first 1
$datasource = $DataSourceName
$objdataSource = $Proxy.GetItemDataSources($thisreport.path)

#Generate new data source reference
$proxyNamespace = $objdataSource.GetType().Namespace
$DataSourceReference = new-object ("$proxynamespace.DataSourceReference")
$DataSourceReference.Reference = ($allitems | where {($_.Type -eq "DataSource") -and ($_.Name -eq $datasource)}).Path
$objdataSource[0].item = $DataSourceReference

Write-Verbose "Updating datasource"
$Proxy.SetItemDataSources($ThisReport.Path, $objdataSource)  //$ThisReport.Path I am getting this as /MyReport
```

> #
>   
>   !!!! ERRORS HAVE BEEN ENCOUNTERED !!!!
>   
>   #
>
> Exception calling "SetItemDataSources" with "2" argument(s):
>   "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The path of the item ''
>   is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long;
>   other re strictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the
>   path must start with slash. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidItemPathException:
>   The path of the item '' is not vali d. The full path must be less than
>   260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is
>   in native mode, the path must start with slash.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetItemDataSources(String
>   Item, DataSource[] DataSources, Guid batchId)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetItemDataSources(String
>   Item, DataSource[] DataSources)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.SetItemDataSources(String
>   ItemPath, DataSource[] DataSources)"
>
> #

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I figured out why it is throwing because of this line

```
$DataSourceReference.Reference = ($allitems | where {($_.Type -eq "DataSource") -and ($_.Name -eq $datasource)}).Path
```

This should be

```
$DataSourceReference.Reference = ($allitems | where {(**$_.TypeName** -eq "DataSource") -and ($_.Name -eq $datasource)}).Path
```

It is not able to set the DataSource path to the root `(/)` as it is returning null. Please try and let me know